# Curl request working in terminal but not in php

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Trying to do this in php

```
curl -X POST
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
-H "Accept: application/json"
-u xxx:xxx
-d '{
    "broadcast": true,
    "title": "Hello World",
    "message": "from Kumulos Push"
}' "https://push.kumulos.com/notifications"
```

In php I have this...

```
$ch = curl_init( 'https://push.kumulos.com/notifications' );

curl_setopt_array( $ch, [
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $data ),
    ],
    CURLOPT_USERPWD        => 'xxx:xxx',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $data,
] );

$resp = htmlentities( curl_exec( $ch ) );
```

Still in php I get redirected whereas in command line I get the expected response...

### UPDATE

It returns this HTML in PHP, whereas in command line I get expected JSON

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=https://push.kumulos.com" />

        <title>Redirecting to https://push.kumulos.com</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="https://push.kumulos.com">https://push.kumulos.com</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

### Update : data sent with php request

```
$data = json_encode( [
    "title"     => "Hello World",
    "message"   => $message,
    "installIds" => [ $deviceToken, ],
] );
```

### Update : Expected output ( received in command line curl )

```
{  
"appId":9999,
"source":2,
"status":1,
"filters":{  
    "installIds":[  
        "xxx"
    ]
},
"title":"Test",
"message":"3 new questions on Tomorrow Times!",
"data":null,
"isBackgroundData":false,
"url":null,
"targetedRecipients":0,
"expectedResolutionSteps":0,
"completedResolutionSteps":0,
"expectedBatches":0,
"completedBatches":0,
"updatedAt":"2017-06-16T04:58:54+0000",
"createdAt":"2017-06-16T04:58:54+0000",
"id":13976
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark from Kumulos Tech Support here.

The problem is caused by the absence of HTTP headers in the request.

`CURLOPT_HEADER` is used (`true` or `false`) to indicate whether or not headers will be included in the request.

To actually set the headers you need to use `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`

Without the headers, the request will be redirected as you have seen.

Please find below some example PHP code to send a broadcast push to all subscribed installs of your app using the Kumulos Push API.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$postData = json_encode( array (
    "broadcast" => true,
    "title" => "Test Broadcast",
    "message" => "Test from PHP" )
);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array( $curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL            => "https://push.kumulos.com/notifications",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array (
            'content-type: application/json',
            'accept: application/json',
            'content-length: ' . strlen($postData),
        ),
    CURLOPT_USERPWD        => 'apiKey:serverKey',
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $postData,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
] );

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Mark!!! I knew I must be missing on something fundamental like this but couldn't figure out what...   Thanks again! Have a lovely day! 

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `curlopt_followlocation => 1`. Also what are you expecting to return?  If you are -xpecting something other than a truthy falsy value you need to remove `curlopt_returntransfer`. Also if you are sending post just use `CURLOPT_POST => 1`

---

**Example**

```
$ch = curl_init( 'https://push.kumulos.com/notifications' );

curl_setopt_array( $ch, [
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => [
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $data ),
    ],
    CURLOPT_USERPWD        => 'xxx:xxx',
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $data,
] );

$resp = htmlentities( curl_exec( $ch ) );
```

Since you are using

```
htmlentities(...)
```

I definitely assume you need to remove **CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER**.

> #### CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER
>
> TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

---

> #### CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION
>
> TRUE to follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header (note this is recursive, PHP will follow as many "Location: " headers that it is sent, unless CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is set).

---

## Edit

To address new information from the user.  Please the Kumulos documentation.  Are you sure this is a post request and not a put request?  Do you need to send an API key?  Can you post the JSON data you are sending?

From our conversation it appears you now are recieving a 200 instead of a 3XX after the changes were implemented.  Please update question accordingly.  The issue now is somewhere in your data I believe

Comment: Thanks :) It returns JSON containing details about the action performed... ATM it returns some HTML...

Comment: Updated question with response php curl request returns... Setting `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to false didn't do the trick for me...

Comment: Are you sure this is a post request and not a put request? Do you need to send an API key? Can you post the JSON data you are sending?

Comment: Updated question :) Can you share the link to docs you are referring to?

Comment: and yes, using `POST` ;)

Comment: Yes those are the same documents I am using.  Notice that you do not have an API_KEY in your header.  Also your JSON is malformed (see the comma in the array).  Have you generated an API key?  Also just to clarify push and post are different things

Comment: `json_encode` will take care of that for me :) I shared PHP code that generates JSON, in php we can have trailing commas in array ;)

Comment: Yeah, I'm using API key in `CURLOPT_USERPWD        => 'xxx:xxx',`...
Coz curl has `-u` flag...

Comment: This line should tell php curl that I want to use custom `POST` method, righty? `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => 'POST',` Or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you post an output of the JSON?  Also can you tell me what you are recieving when you run CURL from shell?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146817/discussion-between-christopher-maggiulli-and-shramee).

Comment: Sure, added to question :) Thanks :)